# Fail to bounce type - Firebase error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

in my app i have json structure like this

```
{
 -JyDZ5cSaDr-mOPzKNFR: {
images: "201509022027404cbef290-b5d4-4e2b-9579-f8321a260b24.jpg"
language: "tamil"
likes: 10
shares: 0
tittle: "I wish I could illegally download clothes"
user: "4cbef290-b5d4-4e2b-9579-f8321a260b24"
}-
-JyD_oSDo6BATTwf-vUK: {
 images: "201509022035004cbef290-b5d4-4e2b-9579-f8321a260b24.jpg"
 language: "tamil"
 likes: 6
 shares: 0
 tittle: "ada muyal pudikra muncha patha theriyatha"
 user: "4cbef290-b5d4-4e2b-9579-f8321a260b24"
}-
```

now i want to add extra field.and firebase will thow bounce error? is there any way to support backward compatibility?

Comment: Please show the code that triggers the error. But most likely you'll find your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108969/why-do-i-get-failed-to-bounce-to-type-when-i-turn-json-from-firebase-into-java/32109104#32109104

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you