# What could be causing the failed bounce to type?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using Firebase, and I am trying to show data from Firebase through my Android app. Yet, when I run the app, it crashes and logcat says "failed to bounce to type". I mimicked the properties of the JSON structure in a java class.

[image: Firebase data]

Here is the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://fbandg.firebaseio.com/");
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
    final TextView textbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    ValueEventListener newCon = ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            fObject obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(fObject.class); //Line 49
            textbox.setText(obj.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the Java class I created:

```
public class fObject
{
    String newCond;
    public String getCondition()
    {
        return newCond;
    }
}
```

The errors produced are the following:

```
firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
com.example.elish_000.myfirstapp.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:49)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here ->Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String newCond = (String) data.get("condition");
            textbox.setText(newCond);
            fObject obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(fObject.class); //Line 49
            textbox.setText(obj.toString());
        }

Comment: Why are you setting the value of your textBox two times?

Comment: did u get the solution?

Comment: @parag No. Log cat gave the same errors

Comment: @ParagKadam Hey Parag, it works. It just that the activity displays "DataSnapShot {key = condition, value = Steamed} instead of just displaying "Steam".

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://fbandg.firebaseio.com");
final TextView textbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        fObject fobject = new fObject();
        fobject.setNewCondition(dataSnapshot.child("condition").getValue().toString());
        textbox.setText(fobject.getNewCondition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

modify your fObject class,

```
public class fObject
{
    String newCond;
    public String getNewCond()
    {
        return newCond;
    }

    public void setNewCond(String cond)
    {
        newCond = cond;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's JSON-to-Java mapper uses a JavaBean pattern to determine how to map fields. For a class to be a valid JavaBean, the field name and the getter/setter need to match.

To make your class work, change it to:

```
public class fObject
{
    String newCond;
    public String getNewCond()
    {
        return newCond;
    }
}
```

You can then read it from a `DataSnapshot` with:

```
fObject obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(fObject.class);
```

I've covered this extensively a while ago: [Why do I get "Failed to bounce to type" when I turn JSON from Firebase into Java objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108969/why-do-i-get-failed-to-bounce-to-type-when-i-turn-json-from-firebase-into-java?rq=1). You should probably read that too.