# onChildAdded not retrieve data on android app firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, marker

I have this problem in android using `firebase` `onChildAdded` function. I want to retrieve some data that I send in android Database in this structure

[image]

This is a structure to save marker data Lat, Lang and address or desc,

I want to retrieve in a activity all markers added by user from another activity in my application in real time.

**This is the class**

```
public class add_marker {
        private String Lat;
        private String Lang;
        private String Adresa;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public add_marker(){}


    add_marker(String Lat, String Lang) {
        this.Lat = Lat;
        this.Lang = Lang;
    }

    public String getLat(){
            return Lat;
        }

        public String getLang(){
            return Lang;
        }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////

and the code where I use this class to create the object m1 is:
then I want to use the object to re create the markers on the other map activity.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://db.firebaseio.com/markera");

        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
               add_marker m1 = snapshot.getValue(add_marker.class);
               // System.out.println("Lat: " + m1.getLat());
                //System.out.println("Lang: " + m1.getLang());
                System.out.println("hello");

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            } ......
```

I am trying to create an object with the data from the database and then load them in a map fragment on the activity one by one each time a child is added, 
you can check the object m1.

every time I try to run this activity the app crash.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108969/why-do-i-get-failed-to-bounce-to-type-when-i-turn-json-from-firebase-into-java

Comment: I am trying to do the same but it is not working

Comment: */
public class add_marker {
        private String Lat;
        private String Lang;
        //private String Adresa;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public add_marker(){
            
        }

public String getLat(){return Lat;}

    public String getLang(){ return Lang;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "add_marker{Lat='" + Lat +"', Lang='" + Lang +"'}";
}

    }

Comment: this is the change in the class the object creation is like this


 ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
               add_marker m1 = snapshot.getValue(add_marker.class);
              // this crash the app

            }