# how to get the object from firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have user class like this

```
public class User{
int id;
String description;
String shortDescription;
String photo;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getShortDescription() {
    return shortDescription;
}

public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
    this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
}

public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
}
```

i am fetching the user stored on my firebase using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter like as shown below

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserHolder>(
                    User.class,
                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    UserHolder.class,
                    mRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(UserHolder userHolder, User u, int i) {
                    userHolder.mText.setText(u.getDescription());
                }
            };
```

**But the issue is is when the firebase key of the user object is like**

```
 > -KDY9Pna7XqgFkyCHKFJ
```

this then its **working fine** but if the **firebase key** is like

```
 > c5755a68-69a7-4464-956e-c2f94d9b387d
```

this **unique id** then it is giving an **error**

```
> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
```

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: 
> main Process: in.rofr, PID: 12399
> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
> at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
> at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161)
> at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
> at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5465)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5498)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4735)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4611)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
> at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903)
> at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1183)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2116)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1873)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
> ```

What is the **exact issue**, i am not getting can anyone **help me?**

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: can i know what is **s** in this line **userHolder.mText.setText(s.getDescription());** i dnt find where did you declare that one.

Comment: sorry its u.getDescription()

Comment: Still little confuse, Can you tell about **key**. is that key in firebase or key of Object while debug ?

Comment: Well the problem is JSON property does not  maps  correctly please look this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32109104/5955593)

Comment: Without seeing a user in JSON (as text, no screenshot please) and the **full** stack trace (the more interesting error message is nested) it will be impossible to help. But the answer @Kathi linked is indeed a good start. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on top of the class like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserModel {

}
```

This might work because Firebase uses Jackson library to serialise/deserialise JSON and the use of @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) is to ignore new properties (properties that are not declared in the class) as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455563/2331705