# Unable to fetch user's gmail email address through Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app which use Firebase` as a BaaS.

I have integrated Google Sign-in and I want to fetch user's name, email address and profile pic.

I have successfully fetched the name and profile pic, but I'm unable to fetch the email address.

Here's Google API client setup:

```
/* Setup the Google API object to allow Google+ logins */
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
```

Here's what I have done to fetch user's data:

```
public void fetchDataFromGoogle() {

        if (authData != null) {
            if (authData.getProvider().equals("google")) {

                googleName = (String) authData.getProviderData().get("displayName");
                googleEmail = (String) authData.getProviderData().get("email");
                googleImage = (String) authData.getProviderData().get("profileImageURL");

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This code have successfully fetched the name and profile pic, but it is returning `null` for the email address.

Please let me know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Can you double check the "email" string used as a key on both when you are saving to firebase and when you are fetching it...?

Comment: @DroidGEEK he is not fetching it from firebase, he is fetching it from google

Comment: Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

its how I am fetching it...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is your case, but one situation where you are able to get other fields but getEmail returns null is when in Firebase console > Authentication > Sign-In Methods you allow "creation of multiple accounts with the same email address"

There's a [closed bug report](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/266) already filed with google:

> When you go to the **Auth > Sign-In Methods** page of your project in the Firebase console. do you have **One account per email address** on or off? If you allow multiple accounts per email address, **you will get null** for FirebaseUser.**getEmail()**

[image]

You have to use the option: "Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" or else **FirebaseUser.getEmail() will return null**

Ps: only users who first logged in after the option was turned off will be able to use this method successfully

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to also request the `email` scope. From the [Firebase documentation for Google authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html):

> Here is an example of Google login where the session will expire upon browser shutdown and we also request the extended email permission:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) { /* Your Code */ }, {
  remember: "sessionOnly",
  scope: "email"
});
```

See also my answer there: [Firebase and new Google Sign-In on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631750/firebase-and-new-google-sign-in-on-android)