# Can't retrieve data From Firebase through Java Object Class(POJO)

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to fetch the data from Firebase to Android. I am using the POJO (Java object class) method to display the values.

This is how I have arranged my data on Firebase:

[image: 1]

This is my POJO class "MonitoringPojo.java".

```
public class MonitoringPojo {

Results results;

public Results getResults(){

    return results;

}

public class Results {
    double MaxLat;
    double MaxLng;
    double  MinLat;
    double MinLng;
    String Congestion_Status;


    public double getMaxLat() {
        return MaxLat;
    }

    public double getMaxLng() {
        return MaxLng;
    }

    public double getMinLat() {
        return MinLat;
    }
    public double getMinLng() {
        return MinLng;
    }
    public String getCongestion_Status() {
        return Congestion_Status;
    }
}
```

}

This is where I am trying to fetch and display the values from the FireBase via that POJO class.

```
 MonitoringPojo pojo = dataSnapshot.getValue(MonitoringPojo.class);
            double sourceOne = pojo.results.getMaxLat();
            double destinationOne = pojo.results.getMaxLng();
            double sourceTwo= pojo.results.getMinLat();
            double destinationTwo= pojo.results.getMinLng();
            String fetchedColor=pojo.results.getCongestion_Status().toString();
            DrawPolygon2(sourceOne,destinationOne,sourceTwo,destinationTwo,fetchedColor);
```

But unfortunatley I am getting nothing displayed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to retrieve the data from your `model`, you need to create `the no argument constructor` of the class and also the constructor for each variable. Also you need to provide public setter in the same way you have the getters.

An example is this:

`public void setMaxLat(long maxLat) {this.maxLat= maxLat;}`

You need to set this setters for all of your variables.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added the no argument constructor for the class and the setter methods. But now I am getting the following error . " E/UncaughtException: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type "

Comment: E/UncaughtException: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type.

Comment: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "MinLng" (class com.example.shahroze.sdsmap_v1.MonitoringPojo), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "results"])

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108969/why-do-i-get-failed-to-bounce-to-type-when-i-turn-json-from-firebase-into-java) post to understand how this works.

Comment: Is there everything ok?

Comment: I understood the whole format, I even converted my data into that format as suggested. But still I was facing problems. For now I have decided to move ahead. But Thankyou for your continous support!