# com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in using Firebase and Android. I have a project to save an order and a payment in one child and show them all in adapter. But it show error when get data with `postSnapshot` from model class. I dont know where the fault in my project. Error like this:

> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type

and

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "payment"

My firebase structure looks like:

[image: firebase structure]

And then this is my java code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
String status = "orderSucces";
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase-d8a8a.firebaseio.com/order");
    orderID = "-Kxi37Ro2oCPxQkb5L5u";
    Query query = ref.child(status).orderByChild("orderID").equalTo(orderID);
    query.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    OrderModel data = postSnapshot.getValue(OrderModel.class);
                    orderModel.add(data);
                    adapter = new Adapter(getApplication(), orderModel);
                    //adding adapter to recyclerview
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**OrderModel.java**

```
public class PemesananModel implements Serializable {

    public String orderID, paymentID, buyerName, buyerPhone, paymentMethod;

    PemesananModel() {}

    public PemesananModel(String orderID, String paymentID, String buyerName, String buyerPhone, String paymentMethod) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
        this.paymentID = paymentID;
        this.buyerName = buyerName;
        this.buyerPhone = buyerPhone;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }

    public String getOrderID() {
        return orderID;
    }

    public void setOrderID(String orderID) {
        this.orderID = orderID;
    }

    public String getPaymentID() {
        return paymentID;
    }

    public void setPaymentID(String paymentID) {
        this.paymentID = paymentID;
    }

    public String getBuyerName() {
        return buyerName;
    }

    public void setBuyerName(String buyerName) {
        this.buyerName = buyerName;
    }

    public String getBuyerPhone() {
        return buyerPhone;
    }

    public void setBuyerPhone(String buyerPhone) {
        this.buyerPhone = buyerPhone;
    }

    public String getPaymentMethod() {
        return paymentMethod;
    }

    public void setPaymentMethod(String paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Failed to bounce to type" when I turn JSON from Firebase into Java objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108969/why-do-i-get-failed-to-bounce-to-type-when-i-turn-json-from-firebase-into-java)

Answer (score 2):

Since your JSON doesn't have a property called `payment`, it seems like you're simply reading the data at the wrong level in your JSON tree.

The solution is to attach your listener on the correct level in the tree, like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference paymentRef = rootRef
    .child("order")
    .child("orderSucces")
    .child(orderID)
    .child("payment");
```